# Object vararg and int vararg compilation error

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Why is the below code giving compilation error "The method show(Object[]) is ambiguous for the type VarArgs"?.

Error in line show(10,20,30);

```
public class VarArgs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        show(10,20,30);
    }

    private static void show(Object... args){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    private static void show(int... arry){
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }
}
```

JDK : jdk1.6.0_23

Comment: Thanks Tunaki. Not sure its a duplicate because there overloading is with int vararg with Integer vaarg. When show(10,20,30) is made, why there is a confusion?. On the other hand private static void show(Integer... arry) works..

Answer (score 1):

You should first read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and then pass an int array instead of 3 ints in show method.

What is happening here is Java compiler is automatically boxing int to Integer class and since Integer class is a subclass of Object class both versions of show() method could accept show(int[]) and hence compiler is throwing ambiguous error.

Comment: show(int[]) cannot take show(10,20,30). Also if i change the second method to private static void show(Integer... arry), it works.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, by show(int[]) I mean calling show method with an int array as it's paramter.

Comment: For a vararg, show(10,20,30) is an array passed, right?. What i think is, second method is boxed to Integer and then widened to Object. Not sure though.